# Dynamically invoke object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object :

```
const Foo = {
  bar: function(baz) { ... }
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
let x = 'Foo';
let y = 'cookies';

x.bar(y);
```

I tried using eval: `eval(x + '.bar' + '(' + y + ')');` but it's not working.

I cannot use window, this is code will not run in a browser. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Foo = {
  bar: function(baz) { 
    console.log(baz);
  }
}

let x = 'Foo';
let y = 'cookies';

eval(x).bar(y);
```

Comment: Gotcha, I updated the code. Does this look like what youre looking for?

Comment: No problem, I removed my comments from my original answer since I didnt realize `'Foo'` needed to be a string. [Also, some cautions about eval](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/)

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap `Foo` in another object and call the function with bracket notation.

```js
const Foo = {
        bar: function(baz) { console.log(baz); }
    };

var object = { Foo },
    x = 'Foo',
    y = 'cookies';

object[x].bar(y);
```

Comment: Foo is actually `const Foo = require('Foo')`;

Comment: you could stil wrap it in an object.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstood your question if you want to pass 'y' as a string to eval function you should scape it.

```
const Foo = {
  bar: function(baz) { console.log(baz);}
}
var x = 'Foo';
var y = 'cookie';
eval(x+'.bar("'+y+'")');
```

Otherwise cookie will be treated as a variable like 'Foo' inside x.